# Unity. Отображение шаблонного класса в инспекторе

Tags: c#, unity3d, generics, сериализация

Есть шаблонный класс

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Point<T> {


    public T x { get; set; }
    public T y { get; set; }

    public Point(T x, T y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

И я пытаюсь отобразить поле в инспекторе с типом этого класса, но в инспекторе ничего не отображается

```
[SerializeField]
public Point<float> paddingContent = new Point<float>(15f, 10f);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Почему возникает данная проблема?

Inspector работает **только** с **сериализуемыми** типами. Когда Inspector пытается отрисовать класс, наследованный от MonoBehaviour, он напрямую с объектом не работает, первое, что он делает, - просит объект сериализоваться, после чего отображает сериализованные данные.

Из-за подобной работы Inspector`а и возникает проблема отображения Generic типов: Unity сериализовать Generic, увы, не умеет.

---

### Как решить данную проблему?

**Короткий ответ - никак**, нужно писать свою сериализацию, благо Unity это позволяет, но кастомные решения плохо дружат с родной сериализацией, так что это довольно сложный и в общем случае нерабочий вариант. Так что напрямую эту проблему практически невозможно решить.

**Но есть одна лазейка:**

Хоть Unity и не сериализует `GenericPoint<float>`, но зато может сериализовать наследуемый от него класс с подставленным типом `T`:

```
public class GenericPoint<T> {
    [SerializeField]
    private T x, y;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class GenericPointFloat : GenericPoint<float> { }
```

Unity успешно сможет сериализовать и десериализовать подобный класс:

```
public class FoobarComponent : MonoBehaviour {
    public GenericPointFloat floatPoint;
}
```

А поскольку сериализация смогла, то и inspector сможет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примера ради (точка, имеющая координаты типа GameObject или List, смысла не имеет):

```
[System.Serializable]
public class GenericPointFloat : GenericPoint<float> { }

[System.Serializable]
public class GenericPointInt : GenericPoint<int> { }

[System.Serializable]
public class GenericPointGameObject : GenericPoint<GameObject> { }

[System.Serializable]
public class GenericPointList : GenericPoint<List<int>> { }
```

Добавляем переменные в тестовый класс:

```
public class FoobarComponent : MonoBehaviour {
    public GenericPointFloat      floatPoint;
    public GenericPointInt        intPoint;
    public GenericPointGameObject gameObjectPoint;
    public GenericPointList       listPoint;
}
```

И любуемся правильным инспектором:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]